# Vim opens Makefile with uppercased name in new tab

Tags: macos, vim, makefile

My vim:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4`
Included patches: 1-898, 8056
Normal version without GUI.
```

My ~/.vimrc: `syntax on`

My OS: `macOS Sierra 10.12.3`

I have a file named `Makefile`. When I open it in vim with `vim Makefile` from terminal everything works fine.

But when I open it in a new tab with `:tab new Makefile` from within vim, it displays the name as `MAKEFILE`. Also the syntax highlighting stops working. Also when I run `:!ECHO %` it displays 'MAKEFILE' uppercased. When I save the file, it also uppercases the name on the filesystem.

I don't have this problem with any files that have suffix, only with files without suffix. File named `Abcd` for example opens lowercased as `abcd`. It seems it opens it upper/lower cased randomly but always the same way for one particular file.

How do I make Vim open files in new tabs with original name?

Comment: I have exactly the same OS and vim versions and I can't replicate this.

Comment: Default Vim still has the issue but MacVim works fine.